# Manual IP configuration disappears

Tags: 14.04, networking

Note: if I connect the two machines via my regular network switch and use `auto` configuration, they don't do this.

---

I have configured a private network between two machines and this works for minutes at a time, but then one or both will lose it's IP address.

```
$ route -n ; ifconfig eth5
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth5

eth5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:53:09:4b:c5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:53ff:fe09:4bc5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:486592 (486.5 KB)  TX bytes:737905 (737.9 KB)
          Interrupt:52
```

after a couple of minutes the adapter changes to

```
eth5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:53:09:4b:c5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:53ff:fe09:4bc5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2656 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3869 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:504490 (504.4 KB)  TX bytes:746276 (746.2 KB)
          Interrupt:52
```

I have tried setting the `interfaces`

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

iface eth5 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

If I run this manually again, it works again

```
sudo ifconfig eth5 192.168.1.2
```

How do I set the configuration so it doesn't keep getting reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're missing out on a `auto eth5` line above `iface eth5 inet static`.
2. Check that all other interface management processes aren't using the interface. A common mistake is to still have a `dhclient` process (DHCPd client) running when the interface was set to DHCP before. Verify using for example with `pgrep -l "(NetworkManager|dhclient)"`.

In general, learn to use `ifup <interface>` and `ifdown <interface>` commands instead of manually configuring it. Also it's a good practice to always bring the interface down before editing the `interfaces` file because of results like mentioned in 2 could happen otherwise.

Comment: Adding the `auto` line and using `ifup` worked.